# Android Studio: Intents keep crashing the application

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

I literally have two different projects open with the EXACT same code, except that they have different class names.

One of them works fine, the other crashes when I click the button that executes the intent. It is driving me crazy.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), New.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Although I really don't know how useful this is, because this exact code works in a different project.

Comment: check your `activity_main`  has xml button tag with `button2` as `@+id` and posting logcat details and complete related code is a good thing on SO :)

Comment: yeah it does. I checked multiple times. I'm using my S6 to run it, and my logcat keeps going on non-stop, so I can't post anything of relevance.

Comment: Make sure that you have an activity New, declared in the manifest with the same name. @PavneetSingh, if the button was missing, there would be a NullPointerException and the app won't never open.

Comment: I think it has to do with the NEW versions of studio having 2 XML files (activityxml and content xml). When I use a new activity with 1 java class and 2 associated xml files it works. BUT with only 1 associated XML file to the java, it doesn't.

Comment: @AlexandruDascălu YES! You got it. I had created a java class/XML file duo and linked them together in setContentView but the activity didn't show in the manifest file. THANKS MAN!

Comment: Also, try to filter the logcat by your app' s name. Maybe post here the error log